# Google maps v2 esta retornando "INVALID_REQUEST"

Tags: android

Estou tentando utilizar o Places API do Google, e estou recebendo `INVALID_REQUEST` ao tentar acessa-la.

Essa é a url que estou utilizando:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.7463956,%22-73.9852992&radius=100&sensor=true&+"KEY_API"

Comment: O que é aquele `%22`?

Comment: era isso, na vdd esse %22 foi quando eu colei o codigo aqui, tinha uma aspas ali e ele transformou em %22, mas corrigi isso e funcionou, vlw

Comment: esse `%22` é referente ao carácter de espaço " ". Por algum motivo antes o google maps aceitava coordenadas separadas por espaços. Hoje não aceita mais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o padrão de [encode dos caracteres em HTML](http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html), `%22` significa, decifrado, `"`. Ou seja, a sua URL está sendo interpretada como:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.7463956,"-73.9852992&radius=100&sensor=true&"KEY_API"

Perceba que foi adicionado um `"` antes de sua longitude `-73.9852992` na sua URL.

Para resolver isto, remova `%22` de sua URL para que o caracter `"` seja removido.